# Why is my sublime-build not being picked up automatically?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have the following sass.sublime-build file in my User directory:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/ruby193/bin/ruby.exe", "C:/ruby193/bin/sass", "$file", "$file_path/$file_base_name.css", "--precision", "5"]
,   "selector": "source.scss"
}
```

Yet whenever I open files like Builder.scss the Automatic build is disabled. I have to manually change it to "sass" before it will build (which it does then perfectly fine).

I have similar build files set up with coffee script and it picks up automatically, no problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file name is taking preference over the provided selector.  Is it fixed if you change your build preferences file to `scss.sublime-build`?